# Error when inserting data

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Hi I have created a products table for a database but when I try to insert data into it I get this error:

[image]

This are the table fields:

[image]

The only fields that are required are the first 6 and.This first is the index that is set to autoincrement and the other 5 I have added them.

What is the problem here?

Comment: Can you show us **HOW** you are inserting the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you have assigned a PK to autoincrement... so try this,

```
INSERT INTO products (brandid, subcatid, productname, productprice, productimagepath) VALUES (111,'P111',111,'P111.jpg');
```

Letm me know it helps you or not ?